# SOAP and PHP dont work | Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers

Tags: php, soap

Have this code:

```
set_time_limit(100);
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 100);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

echo '<plaintext style="font-size:20px;">';

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.test/?wsdl', array(
    'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'use'           => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'style'         => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'user_agent'    => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1',
    'connection_timeout' => 120
));

// $result = $client->ValidaRut(array(
$result = $client->__call('ValidaRut', array(
    'rut'       => 11111111,
    'dv'        => '1',
    'cup'       => '1',
    'ipserver'  => gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ,
    'ipcliente' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
));
```

But dont work, php say:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /home/.../test.php:1

what happens? sorry my english.
Dump of data:

```
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
Array
(
    [0] => ValidaRutResponse ValidaRut(ValidaRut $parameters)
)

print_r($client->__getTypes());
Array
(

    [0] => struct ValidaRut {
 double rut;
 string dv;
 string cup;
 string ipserver;
 string ipcliente;
}
    [1] => struct ValidaRutResponse {
 boolean ValidaRutResult;
}
    [2] => int char
    [3] => duration duration
    [4] => string guid
)
```

Safe mode is off. I use WHM/cPanel, library is installed. Thanks.

Comment: Your error message indicates your soap call is on line 1.. but your example code suggests otherwise. Also, you're getting a SoapException but you haven't enabled them in your soap client constructor. Are you're showing the right code?

Comment: The line error is "$result = $client->__call('ValidaRut', array(..." is last line. The error is not in the connect, is when call the function.

Comment: The PHP native SOAP extension is the root of all evil and the cause of my early onset baldness. I *highly* recommend using [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) instead.

Comment: That doesn't explain why your error message references line 1. Enable tracing and dump the last request headers and body.

Comment: Trace: http://pastebin.com/CZ2HCHDY , thanks deverandom, i testing with nuSoap.

Comment: With NuSOAP: http://pastebin.com/m6QEY1ub

Comment: NuSOAP dont work, dont support SOAP 1.2 protocol, only 1.1.

Comment: Original SOAP: http://www.vidasecurity.cl/WsVivaMejor?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me., The server malfunctioned.